samba automounting script written in Python
My question is about the design of the program, if we could simplify the code logic in a or b function or remove, reuse, or create more functions. Also, another question I have is if it's ok to handle fstab this way, how do you handle a critical file like this? I am creating a temporal file so if something terrible happens at least we could manually recover that file.
Here is the code:
import os
import time
from getpass import getpass


# -----------------FOLDER CREATION-----------------------------------
# Create the credentials folder in specified path
def create_credentials_folder(path_credentials):
    if os.path.exists(path_credentials):
        print(" Folder for credentials already found. Using it...")
    else:
        try:
            print(" Folder not found, creating one...")
            os.makedirs(path_credentials, 0o700, exist_ok=True)
            print(" Folder for credentials created...")
        except Exception as error:
            print(f" Can't create credentials folder: {error}")


# ------------------FILE CREDENTIALS CREATION--------------------------
def create_credentials_file(user, passw, domain, credentials_file):
    try:
        print(f"{credentials_file}")
        if os.path.exists(credentials_file):  # File Exists Already
            overwrite = (
                input("File already found, do you want to rewrite it? y/n: ").lower()
                == "y"
            )
            if not overwrite:  # We Shouldn't Overwrite it
                print("New credentials file Not Created...")
                return
        with open(credentials_file, "w", 0o600) as file:  # w already overwrite it.
            file.write(f"username={user}\n")
            file.write(f"password={passw}\n")
            file.write(f"domain={domain}\n")
        print("File created")
    except Exception as error:
        print(f"Can't create file: {error}")
# ------------------------CREATE FSTAB TEMP FILE---------------------------------
def fstab_temp():
    try:
        with open("/etc/fstab", "r") as file:
            fstab = file.read()
        with open("fstab-temp", "w+") as file:
            file.write(fstab)
        print("Fstab temp created...")
    except Exception as error:
        print(f"Can't create fstab temp copy {error}")

# ------------------------DELETE FSTAB TEMP FILE------------------------------------
def delete_fstab_temp():
    try:
        os.remove("fstab-temp")
        print("Fstab temp deleted...")
    except Exception as error:
        print(f"Can't delete fstab temp {error}, please delet it manually")

# ---------------------------MODIFYING FSTAB----------------------------------
def fstab_modify(entry):    
        fstab_temp()
        print("Temporal fstab copy created")
        # Read existing entries from fstab
        with open("/etc/fstab", "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()         

        # Check if the entry already exists
        if any(line.strip() == entry.strip() for line in lines):
            print(
                f"A line in /etc/fstab for {entry} already exists. New entry not added."
            )
        else:
            # Append the new entry to fstab
            with open("/etc/fstab", "a") as f:
                f.write(entry)
                print(f"New entry on /etc/fstab for {entry} added.")

            # Print the updated contents of fstab
            print("Updated /etc/fstab:")
            with open("/etc/fstab", "r") as f:
                print(f.read())


# ----------------------SHARE FOLDER CHECK-----------------------------
def check_folder_share(mount_folder):
    try:
        if os.path.exists(mount_folder):
            print("Folder for smb mounting found, using it.")
        else:
            os.makedirs(mount_folder, exist_ok=True)
            os.chown(mount_folder, 1000, 1000)
    except Exception as error:
        print(f"Can't create folder: {error}")


# ---------------------VALIDATING FSTAB------------------------------
def validate_fstab():
    try:
        # Reload daemons
        os.system("systemctl daemon-reload")
        # Mount all entrances in /etc/fstab
        mount_result = os.system("mount -a")
        if mount_result != 0:
            print("Error mounting entries in /etc/fstab.")            
            return False
        else:
            print("Entries successfully mounted in /etc/fstab.")
            return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error validating /etc/fstab: {e}")
        return False


# --------------------------RETURN TO BEGINNING IF ERROR----------------------
def cleanup_func(credentials_file, fstab_entr, fstab_loc, mnt_fol):
    if os.path.exists(credentials_file):
        os.remove(credentials_file)
        print("Removed credentials file")
    if os.path.exists(mnt_fol):
        os.rmdir(mnt_fol)
        print("Removed mount folder created.")

    with open(fstab_loc, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open(fstab_loc, "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if not line.startswith(fstab_entr):
                f.write(line)
        print("Removed entry from /etc/fstab.")
        print("validating /etc/fstab: ")
        if validate_fstab():
            print("/etc/fstab validated.")
            delete_fstab_temp()
            print("Removed temporary fstab.")
        else:
            print("/etc/fstab not validated. Please, check /etc/fstab!!!!")


# ----------------------------MAIN--------------------------------------------
def main():
    ############### Configurable Variables ###################################
    mnt_folder = input("Local folder address:")
    samba_server_ip = input("IP address Samba Server:")
    share_name = input("Share Name: ")
    samba_user = input("Samba username: ")
    samba_pass = getpass("Samba password: ")
    samba_domain = input("Domain(optional): ")
    samba_path_credentials = "/etc/samba/credentials"
    credentials_filename = samba_server_ip + "_credentials"
    fstab_location = "/etc/fstab"
    credentials_filepath = samba_path_credentials + "/" + credentials_filename
    fstab_entry = f"//{samba_server_ip}/{share_name} {mnt_folder} cifs rw,x-systemd.automount,credentials={credentials_filepath},uid={samba_user},gid={samba_user} 0 0\n"
    ###########################################################################

    print("Creating the folder...")
    time.sleep(1)
    create_credentials_folder(samba_path_credentials)

    print("Creating the credentials file inside '/etc/samba/credentials'...")
    time.sleep(1)
    create_credentials_file(samba_user, samba_pass, samba_domain, credentials_filepath)

    print("Creating mount folder...")
    time.sleep(1)
    check_folder_share(mnt_folder)

    print("Adding fstab entry...")

    time.sleep(1)
    fstab_modify(fstab_entry)

    print("checking fstab entries...")
    time.sleep(1)
    if validate_fstab():
        print(
            "All fstab entries validated and mounted :) Enjoy your new SMB automount!"
        )
    else:
        cleanup_func(credentials_filepath, fstab_entry, fstab_location, mnt_folder)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


My idea is passing this to a GUI now.
It's my first project, I accept better ways to do it.
https://github.com/xndpxs/smb_share_gui/blob/main/create_samba_share.py

This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please [edit] to add sufficient motivating context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. Questions should include a description of what the code does.

One additional thing that hasn't been mentioned: error handling.
First, it is not a good practise to catch generic Exception. There are use cases for this (for example in a GUI application, you could add a generic exception handler in your run loop), but this seems not be one of them.
Check which kind of exceptions can be raised, and think about how to handle them.
Second, you are handling the exceptions in your functions only by printing information, but the caller gets no information of this. So if you couldn't create the directory for some reason, the caller doesn't get notified of it and will just continue. There are a few possibilities how to handle this:

catch the exception, log and reraise, for the caller to either handle it, or just bail out with the callstack
catch the exception, and raise a specific exception (the logging can be done by the caller in this case)
catch the exception, log and return false in the exception handler, true otherwise, and let the caller check the return value
don't catch the exception at all (not too user-friendly, but it will show the callstack and the excpetion before bailing out)

One thing I didn't understand - why these sleep(1) calls in main are needed?
And for something completely different: you probably know that Terry Pratchett quote "Multiple exclamation marks are a sure sign of a diseased mind" - don't do this in your logs :)

Please do not post premature answers. If the question is incomplete and there's already a comment on the question pointing it out, allow the author of the question to fix their post before answering. Once answers come in, edits can invalidate answers which creates headaches for everyone involved.

Sorry, I had missed that! Will check next time.

Superfluous comments:
create_credentials_folder() is a good function name. Preceding it with this:
# -----------------FOLDER CREATION-----------------------------------

is only distracting. If you want to document a function, do it with a doctstring.
In create_credentials_file(), we have:
if os.path.exists(credentials_file):  # File Exists Already

Here you're only reiterating what the method says, exists is clear enough.
Going forward, we have:
with open(credentials_file, "w", 0o600) as file:  # w already overwrite it.

This isn't useful either. I'd suggest removing all the comments.
Lint and format the code:
Use ruff or black to automatically format the code according to PEP-8. ruff can also lint your code (and fix the problems too), and sort your imports.
Simplify:
file.write(f"username={user}\n")
file.write(f"password={passw}\n")
file.write(f"domain={domain}\n")

Python offers a simpler syntax, if I can persuade you to use more descriptive variable names, that is:
file.write(f"{username=}\n")
file.write(f"{password=}\n")
file.write(f"{domain=}\n")

I have changed user to username, and passw to password in the function parameters.
Use type-hints:
The functions would be clearer and more readable if you add type-hints. For instance, consider create_credentials_folder, which takes a single parameter of type str and returns None.
def create_credentials_folder(path_credentials: str) -> None:

Now I can determine what the what the types of the parameters are without having to search where create_credentials_folder() was called, or by having to read all of create_credentials_folder() and try to infer what type they could be. Same goes for the return type.
Typo:
print(f"Can't delete fstab temp {error}, please delet it manually")

Here, "delet" should be "delete".

Please do not post premature answers. If the question is incomplete and there's already a comment on the question pointing it out, allow the author of the question to fix their post before answering. Once answers come in, edits can invalidate answers which creates headaches for everyone involved.

@Harith Yeah, I will fix the comments and typos (some of them were temporal from function construction) I will use better variable names, but my fear is that I could repeat the  variable names in main function, this is not a problem but it could be confusing. My questions are about the general structure and design, and how to handle such a critical file such as fstab, right now I am creating a temp file so we can have a backup if something goes wrong

@Mast Acknowledged.

@Andres Kindly add a description of what the program does to the question.
